# Remove /#/ from link?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a single page application and I'm using this class for routing:
[class code](https://jsfiddle.net/tatakae2140/mop0ya4k/)

then I add routes

```js
export const routes = [
  {
    path: /task-list/,
    callback: () => {
      console.log('callback');
    }
  }
];

export const router = new Router({
  root: '/task-list',
  mode: 'hash',
  routes
});
```

I expect that when loading the site, I will get a link localhost:3000/task-list, but for some reason I get localhost:3000/#/task-list, I can't figure out how to remove this /#/

Comment: it's a hash, and if you don't define `mode` as `hash` you won't get it in the url

Comment: @DeepakKamat when I change `mode: 'hash'` to `mode: 'history'` , the routing stops working altogether, I just load the `http://localhost:3000/ page`, and if I go to `http://localhost:3000/task-list` then it says "Cannot GET /task-list"

Comment: if you are running it on a server you have to make sure you are doing the URL rewrites properly, for angular server it might work, but for e.g if you put it on an apache server make sure you have basic url rewrites in .htaccess